# How to create auto adjustable tableview whose corners are rounded

Tags: ios, uitableview, rounded-corners, tablefooterview

I would like to have a tableview that auto-grows/reduces depending on number of rows and again have the corners rounded it seems very complicated.

for example

I can have a tableview height fixed and set footer null and background color clear then what I said happens but tableview bottom becomes flat.

if i want the bottom to be cornered as well ... then I will have to set the tableview height by caculating progrmatically but it seems over kill to me ?

I rounded the corner using tableview's layer

Any help is welcome